# JCute to perform Concolic Testing - Soot Error

Tags: java, testing, soot

I tried to test a program using JCute. However, I kept getting this error.

> cd /opt/jcute/tmpjcute
>   java -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Dcute.sequential=true cute.instrument.CuteInstrumenter -> keep-line-number -d /opt/jcute/tmpjcute/classes -x com.vladium -x cute -x lpsolve > --app MyTest1
>   env: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/jcute/
>   env: JAVA_LIB_PATH=/opt/jcute/
>   env: PATH=/opt/jcute/:/opt/jcute/
>   env: CLASSPATH=/opt/jcute/tmpjcute/classes:/opt/jcute/jcute.jar:jcute.jar
>   Unknown tag in constant pool: 18 at entry 15
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load classfile: > java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement
>
> > > at soot.coffi.Util.resolveFromClassFile(Util.java:78)
> > >       at soot.CoffiClassSource.resolve(CoffiClassSource.java:37)
> > >       at soot.SootResolver.bringToHierarchy(SootResolver.java:148)
> > >       at soot.SootResolver.processResolveWorklist(SootResolver.java:105)
> > >       at soot.SootResolver.resolveClass(SootResolver.java:89)
> > >       at soot.Scene.loadClass(Scene.java:329)
> > >       at soot.Scene.loadClassAndSupport(Scene.java:314)
> > >       at cute.instrument.CuteInstrumenter.main(CuteInstrumenter.java:182)
> > >       Exit 1

According to this link: 
https://www.se.informatik.uni-kiel.de/en/research/science-blog/soot-tutorial

The error is due to compiling the *classes-to-analyze* with a different java version than you use to execute the command below.

> java -cp *soot-jar*; soot.Main -cp *classes-to-analyze*;*libraries*; -pp soot.Main *main-class*

Unfortunately, I don't fully understand how to fix the error specially that I only have one version of java. Also, I'm using the GUI, so I don't run the command myself. Any help is appreciated.